# How to post only selected items from list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a list bound to view as

```
@model List<DataModels.UseCase>
```

This view contains html form as

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].IsSelected)
        //few other controls as 
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Selection" >
}
```

And In Controller, POST method is like below

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult payment([Bind(Include = "Id,IsSelected// few other properties")] List<UseCase> useCases)
    {
        // Few business logic
        return View();
    }
```

**Please note**- Just for example I have shown only check box control on form, there are other few controls as well.

Now, in this case for example view contains 10 records but out of 10 only 2 are selected then we need to pass only 2 selected records to POST method and not all 10. This is to reduce overload on POST method.

Can we achieve this type of scenario in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, I might implement this on my projects as well.

I could only think of one way-- using javascript, when form is submitted, delete the other form input fields first then resubmit the form.

First is we need to put the input fields inside a parent `div` with class `input-container`, so we could quickly delete all the fields by just deleting the entire `div`. I also added a class `targetCheckbox` to your input field so we could attach an event to it;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
       <div class="input-group">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].IsSelected, new { @class="targetCheckbox" })
           //few other controls as 
        <div class="input-group">
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Selection" >
}
```

We'll need to bind an event to to your form. On form submit, we need to identify which `targetCheckbox` are not checked, then delete the div that contains them. **We also need to replace the indexes of the input fields because ASP.NET MVC model binding must start with 0 and should not skip.** After all that resubmit the form;

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("form").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var index = 0;
         // loop through all the checkbox
         $(".targetCheckbox").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
               // get the parent
               var parent = $(this).closest(".input-container");

               // loop through all the input fields inside the parent
               var inputFieldsInsideParent = $(parent).find(":input");

               // change the index inside the name attribute
               $(inputFieldsInsideParent).each(function(){
                  var name = $(this).attr("name");
                  var firstBracket = name.IndexOf("[");
                  var secondBracket = name.IndexOf("]");

                  if(firstBracket != null && secondBracket != null){
                     // check if this is a valid input field to replace

                     var newName = name.substring(0,firstBracket)+index+name.substring(secondBracket);
                     // result should be IntputFieldName[newIndex].Property

                     // assign the new name
                     $(this).attr("name",newName);
                  }
               });

               index++;
            }else{
               // empty the parent
               $(this).closest(".input-container").html("");
            }
         });

         // submit the form
         $(this).submit();
      });


   });
</script>
```